# Why are these redis commands stuck pending in node and don't resolve?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I'm having trouble using redis commands in node, specifically client.hSet and client.hGetAll, eg:

```
app.post('/user/search', (req, res) => {
    
   const id = req.body.id  
    
   client.hGetAll(id, (err, obj) => {
               
         if(err){
             res.render('someview', {
                 error: 'user does not exist'
             }) 
         } else {
            res.render('someview2', {
                user: obj
            })
...
```

it seems the promise doesn't resolve, and is stuck pending - I've tried both with a valid and non valid key

Also logged the client connection to see if there could be a problem, and I noticed isReady still returns false. Could this be the issue? Am really out of ideas here, and commands work fine in the redis-cli

```
const client = createClient();

console.log('isOpen: '+client.isOpen)
console.log('isReady: '+client.isReady)

client.on('error', err => console.log('Client Error', err));

client.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('Redis Connected');
    console.log('isOpen: '+client.isOpen)
    console.log('isReady: '+client.isReady)
  });
 
async function connect(){  
await client.connect();
}

connect()
```

with output:

```
isOpen: false
isReady: false
Server started on port 3000
Redis Connected
isOpen: true
isReady: false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax looks like Node Redis 3.x syntax. If you’re using Node Redis 4.x, which introduced support for async/await, then you would see this error.

Try this instead:

```js
const obj = await client.hGetAll(is)
```

Also, be sure to mark your callback in `app.post` as `async`.

Comment: Thanks! This solved it for me. Am new to redis and was referring to some older questions so didn't know that could have been the issue!

Comment: Happy to help and glad you got it working!